# Advanced Custom Fields if else issue

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Ok, I think I have a simple fix here.  I'm using ACF to link health reports to specific dogs on a breeder website.  But, not all dogs have the same reports, and I don't want to show a dead link if no ACF value is available.  So, I wanted to use an if statement but can't quite get it to work.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
            $values = get_field('cardiac');
            if($values) {
            echo '<a rel="lightbox" href="'.<?php the_field('cardiac'); ?>.'">Cardiac</a>';
            } else {
            echo '';
            }
        ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `var_dump($values);`?

Comment: I got bool(false) after my test field

Comment: Is this code in a Loop?

Comment: Yes, I added it within a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is that your field type is returning some non-empty value, even if it's not a URL. For instance, do you have "http://" set as a default value for that field in the admin? If that were the case you could need to use the following as your test:

`if( $values || $values !== 'http://' )...`

Alternately, your field may be returning an empty array or some other kind of "unechoable" value.

Try putting `var_dump( $values )` after you set the `$values` variable and see what you're working with. Then adjust your `if()` statement to account for other possible non-empty values you may want to weed out before outputting a link.

---

**Update: Another issue**

Also, you shouldn't use `the_field()` in an echo statement since the_field already echos its output. Change this:

`echo '<a rel="lightbox" href="'.<?php the_field('cardiac'); ?>.'">Cardiac</a>';`

To this:

`echo '<a rel="lightbox" href="'. $values .'">Cardiac</a>';`

Comment: I added the code above but it's still showing the link on fields with no value.  The fields are all set as image url.

Comment: What do you get with the `var_dump()` on a field that you think shouldn't output a link?

Comment: Was I supposed to see an error output?

Comment: Sorry, I got bool(false) after my test field.

Comment: see update. I don't think it'll fix your issue, but it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same type of setup. However, I'm not using the `else` statement. Here's how mine looks (applied with your variables):

```
$values = get_field('cardiac');
    if($values) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_field('cardiac') ;?>" title="<?php echo the_title();?>" data-lightbox="<?php echo the_title();?>">Cardiac</a>
<?php } ;
```

Comment: Weird, I just tried your code, but the link still shows on the fields with no value.